# Using GROUP_CONCAT to produce a value which can be read like a query string

Tags: mysql, group-concat

I understand this has its limitations, but as I have used this a couple of times now, I thought I should check if it's acceptable or if there are any better approaches before I use it again!

Basically, I'm pulling a number of products from a MySQL database. Each product row is linked to a number of other tables, but specifically a properties table where custom properties (name & values pairs) can be set.

I want the query to produce one row per product, despite how many 'properties' the product might have, rather than have to manipulate the result set afterwards.

So, I have done something like this:

```
SELECT 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(pp.name, '=', pp.value) SEPARATOR '&') 
AS properties 
FROM products p
INNER JOIN properties pp ON pp.product_id = p.id
WHERE ...
```

..Which results in a `properties` field in the format `name1=value1&name2=value2` which I can then easily convert to a PHP array using `parse_str($str, $output);` and assign to the product objects for later use.

How does everyone view this approach? How would you do it?

**NOTE**: Just to clarify, I'm not mapping the property names directly to PHP variables (I agree that WOULD be very bad), i'm using `parse_str($str, $output)` which puts the properties into an array `$output`, not directly into variables.

Comment: Make sure you escape (encode) those `&`, `=`, and `;`. Could probably use [`REPLACE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace).

Answer (score 0):

A better approach would be to loop though the rows without the group by, and in the application (PHP in your case) handle the array.

```
$array[$row->group_by_key][$row->name] = $row->value;
```

There is a good chance for things to go wrong with the current `group_concat`, assuming `value` contains a `&` or a `=`. then you have to escape them either before they go in or dynamically.

I know you say you want it all in one row, But why ? If its being parsed either way does it make a difference ?

Comment: I guess one reason for returning one row per product, is for pagination - when you only want the query to return say 10 products.

Comment: you can also do that, Select the 10 you want and do the same query but use `IN(/*YOUR QUERY TO FIND THE 10 YOU WANT*/)`

Answer (score 0):

This can work, but it seems a little dangerous.  The code is making some assumptions that might make it "brittle".  That is, small changes in the future could break this approach.

One assumption is that the variables in PHP are exactly the same as the names in the database.  Sure that is true now, but just wait until someone wants to combine "City" and "State" into a single location property -- or vice versa.  In other words, moving forward the logic may be more than simple assignment.

Another assumption is that your values are numeric (I think quotes would be needed for strings).

A third assumption is the dependency between the database and the application layer.  `group_concat()` is supported only by MySQL.  Another application tool may not support `parse_str()` in exactly the same way.

I will admit, though, that this is a clever solution for getting the properties.  If you are going to go with this approach, I would suggest that you at least put the query into a stored procedure (say `usp_GetAllParameters`) and use the stored procedure for the interface.  This at least separates the database a bit from the application tool.

Comment: No quotes are needed for query strings.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, glad you quite like it. No need for `parse_str`, you could just use `explode` and loop over the name=value pairs.

Comment: Just to point out also, that I'm not mapping the property names directly to PHP variables, i'm using `parse_str($str, $output)` which puts the properties into an array, not directly into variables.

Answer (score -1):

You can try:

```
SELECT 
 p.id,
  GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(pp.name,'=',pp.value) SEPARATOR '&') AS properties
FROM products  p
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT product_id, name, MAX(value)
  FROM properties 
  GROUP BY product_id, name
) pp
ON pp.product_id = p.id
GROUP by p.id
```

or if you don't have multiple records in pp table for every `product_id`+`name`

```
SELECT 
 p.id,
  GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(pp.name,'=',pp.value) SEPARATOR '&') AS properties
FROM products  p
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT DISTINCT product_id, name, value
  FROM properties 
) pp
ON pp.product_id = p.id
GROUP by p.id
```

Comment: Ultimately then, that's using the same logic to group the properties together like a query string..?

Comment: Sorry? I don't understand your question here? what is your doubt/question?

Comment: Your answer is using the same logic to group the properties as in my original question right? So you're saying you approve of that approach?

Comment: So you've originally asked not for help with query? but to code review? If so  I would never use such application architecture where php variables are stored with their names in database. for me that look like you want to go from Boston to New York using transit in Europe. sure if flight cost 10 times less than direct flight today - it could be reasonable. but in long term and if we talk about best practices it can not be a good solution

Comment: Actually, I'm not mapping the property names directly to PHP variables, i'm using `parse_str($str, $output)` which puts the properties into an array, not directly into variables.

Comment: doesn't matter, that looks weird. what is the reason? show the example of data?

Comment: OK, probably a better example is a CMS page, where you can add custom properties, and want to get at these properties from within the page. The properties would be taken from the database and put into an array like `$page->properties = array(name => value, name2 => value2)`. You could then get at the properties like so: `$page->properties['my_custom_propery']`